# Copying arrays to slices in Go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Please can you help me understand how generating a slice from an array works. Why are ID1 and ID2 not the same?

```golang
    a := [2]string{"a", "b"}
    b := [2]string{"c", "d"}
    var z [2][2]string
    z[0] = a
    z[1] = b

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", z)
    var id [][]string
    for _, t := range z {
        temp := t[:]
        id = append(id, temp)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nid1 = %s", id)

    var id2 [][]string
    for _, t := range z {
        temp := t
        id2 = append(id2, temp[:])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nid2 = %s", id2)
```

> [[a b] [c d]]
>
> id1 = [[c d] [c d]]
>      id2 = [[a b] [c d]]

Answer (score 4):

Because the `for range` loop has a single iteration variable which is reused in each iteration. [Spec: For statements: For statements with for clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

> Variables declared by the init statement are re-used in each iteration.

So in your first loop:

```
for _, t := range z {
    temp := t[:]
    id = append(id, temp)
}
```

There is a single `t`, and you slice the same `t` array, so each `temp` slice you append, it will point to the same backing array, which is `t`, and it is overwritten in each iteration, so its value will be the value of the last iteration: `[c d]`.

In your second loop:

```
for _, t := range z {
    temp := t
    id2 = append(id2, temp[:])
}
```

Also there is a single `t` iteration variable, but you make a copy of it: `temp := t`, and you slice this copy, which is detached from `t`, and you append a slice that has the copy as its backing array, which will not be overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: [Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices) by Rob Pike provides a useful background to this.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problematic assignment. It is not what it seems:

```
temp := t[:]
```

Here, `t` is an array and the loop variable. That means at each iteration, the contents of the current array is copied onto `t`. At the first iteration, `t=[]string{"a","b"}`, and a slice is created to point to this array and assigned to `temp`.  At the second iteration `t` is overwritten to become `[]string{"c","d"}`. This operation also overwrites the contents of the first slice. So, you end up with the `{{"c","d"},{"c","d"}}`. The important point here is that contents of `t` gets overwritten, and `t` is shared between the two slices.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop you are saving slices which have the same backing array (ie. the loop variable `t`).  In the second loop you are storing slices using different backing arrays since you make a copy of `t` in `temp`.